# Where does 1/2 in Fourier Transform method of pricing options come from?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, fourier-transform

I am reading Jianwe Zhu's *Applications of Fourier Transform to Smile Modeling*. On page 26, the author is describing how to use the Fourier tranform to price vanilla European call options. If $f_j$ is the Fourier transform of the density function of $x = \ln(S)$ (under measure $Q$), then the probability of exercise under $Q$ (that, is probability $x > \ln(K)$) is

$$F_j (x(T) > a) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{\mathbb{R}} f_j(\phi) \Bigg(\int_a^{\infty} e^{-i\phi x} \mathrm{d}x\Bigg) \mathrm{d}\phi\text{.}\tag{1}$$

This equation makes sense to me. The author then says, equation (2.17),

> A further straightforward calculation yields
>
> $$F_j (x(T) > a) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_j(\phi)\frac{e^{-i\phi a}}{i\phi}\mathrm{d}\phi \text{.}\tag{2}$$

This equation does not make sense to me. Where did equation (2) come from? In particular, where did the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

Answer (score 5):

#### It comes from a direct application of the Fourier inversion theorem for a CDF:

For a general one-dimensional CDF $F_X(x)$, the Fourier inversion theorem can be described as:

\begin{align}
F_X(x) &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-iux}\phi_X(u)}{iu} \: du\\
&=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \mathcal{R}\left[\frac{e^{-iux}\phi_X(u)}{iu}\right] \: du,
\end{align}

where $\phi_X(u)$ is the characteristic function for $X$. *See [Schmelzle (2010)](https://pfadintegral.com/docs/Schmelzle2010%20Fourier%20Pricing.pdf) chapter 3.2 for full derivations*.

---

**With regards to the probability of exercise, $F_j(x(T)>a)$**, first calculate the inner integral:

$$
F_j(x(T)>a) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_j(\phi)\frac{e^{-i\phi a}}{i\phi}\: d\phi.
$$

**Now, see that:**

\begin{align}
F_j(x(T)>a) & = 1-F_j(x(T)\leq a)\\
&= 1 -  \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_j(\phi)\frac{e^{-i\phi a}}{i\phi}\: d\phi\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_j(\phi)\frac{e^{-i\phi a}}{i\phi}\: d\phi,\\
\end{align}
where we — in the second equality — have used that $F_j(x(T)\leq a)$ is a CDF and have inserted its corresponding Fourier inversion counterpart, as seen above. Furthermore, be aware that $f_j(\phi)$ is defined as the characteristic function *per equation (2.13)* in the book.

Comment: +1 We wrote at the same time :-) I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @Kermittfrog No worries :-)